# Android Settings xml

Tags: settings

We have exported the Android Settings of a Device running Android 4.4.3
We want to use this settings.apk to make our own default build for my other android devices (same device, same Android Version). 
We would like to get deploy customized preferences for all devices and we think that is possible to compile this app again with our new preferences included.

How can we deploy the same customized settings on a fleet of devices?

Device: Motorola TC70

Comment: What's your question? Bear in mind that making a custom ROM is off-topic for this site.

Comment: No, we would like to get only a customized Settings app with our preferences.

Comment: Are you aware that Settings has to be a *system app*? That means either it has to be part of the custom ROM, or you need to root the device and install it to the system partition. Does that suit your goals?

Comment: Sorry, I'm an android-Programming-starter. I didn't know that you have to root the device to install a system app.
A custom-rom is for us the best value, do you have a good documentation to build this?

Comment: Perhaps if you [edit] the question to ask **how** to achieve your goal (i.e. deploy the same settings on a fleet of devices), instead of focusing on a particular solution you've already decided on, you might get some helpful answers.

Comment: you are not entirely wrong. We should edit the question instead of focusing on a particular solution . Thank you.

Comment: [This question](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/40719/12442) asks how to do the same for rooted phones. Some of those answers might be helpful to you.

Comment: The problem is that we aren't allowed to root the devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to achieve should be possible using `adb backup` (no root required):

1. Enable ADB USB mode on all devices (have to be done manually, AFAIK).
2. On the pre-configured device perform an `adb backup` of `-all` or if you know it only the relevant system settings app (I think it should be `com.android.providers.settings`?).
3. (optional) Decrypt and decompress the crated backup using [Android Backup Extractor](https://github.com/nelenkov/android-backup-extractor). You can now extract and edit the data in the backup, removing unnecessary/unwanted settings. Afterwards recreate the backup file using the modified data.
4. On each device perform an `adb restore` using the created backup from step 2 or 3.